# Find Method only working once on UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to implement a find function in a userform in a textbox.

Once it detects that 4 digits have been input it looks for this value in a list of models in range ("C39:C102").

It returns the value of the cell that is two cells to the left of it (that's where the name of the group that the model number belongs to is stored), and changes the combobox to select that group automatically.

In the range ("C39:C102"), there are multiple model numbers per individual cell, as in:

> C39= 9070, 4835, 2858, 2853
>
> C40= 2374, 2737, 8857, 9895
>
> etc.

The macro runs the first time after opening the Excel sheet but when I look for a second model number it goes to "not found".

```
Private Sub TextBox5_Change()
    'when user inputs a model number automatically change the combo box below it to correct group
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim modelNum As String

    If Len(TextBox5.Text) = 4 Then
        modelNum = TextBox5.Value
        Set rng1 = Range("C39:C102").Find(modelNum)
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
            ComboBox1.Value = rng1.Offset(0, -2)
            MsgBox "This tool (" & modelNum & ") belongs to " & rng1.Offset(0, -2) & " group."
        Else
            MsgBox modelNum & " not found"
        End If
        TextBox5.Value = ""
        modelNum = ""
        Set rng1 = Nothing
        'ComboBox1.Value = ""
    End If    

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to make sure values are being set as you expect? There's no obvious issues in your code.

Comment: How can I see the variable's values in real time?

Comment: Click anywhere on the `If Len(TextBox5.Text) = 4 Then` line, then press F9 to add a breakpoint. Trigger your code by putting a value into your textbox. It'll run until it hits the breakbpoint, then enter debug mode. From there, press F8 to continue stepping through it line-by-line. You can see your variable values by selecting the Locals window, from the View menu.

Comment: Thank you! I did this and noticed that even after loading the values into the textbox, variable rng1 remains set to Nothing, which explains why it's not finding anything. Now I don't know why.

Comment: Do you always have the same workbook and worksheet selected? If you just call `Range("C39:C102").Find(modelNum)` without specifying a worksheet, it'll use whatever worksheet you happen to have selected.

Comment: Yes, the macro is on the worksheet that it looks for. Could it be since the userform is in focus, it's for a range("C39:C102") but cant find anything and thus it sets rng1 to nothing?

Comment: Before your `Set rng1 = Range("C39:C102").Find(modelNum)` line, I would add a `Range("C39:C102").Select`, to highlight it so you can make sure it's actually searching the correct range

Comment: Did that but still rng1 is dead set to Nothing.

Comment: But did it select the correct range?

Comment: Yes it did select the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me.

Instead of this:

```
Set rng1 = Range("C39:C102").Find(modelNum)
```

try being a bit more explicit:

```
Set rng1 = Range("C39:C102").Find(What:=modelNum, Lookin:=xlValue, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Find() settings in excel are "sticky" and unless you specify them explicitly you'll get whatever settings were last-used.